# How to calculate the occurrences of Char in an ordered [Char]?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, conditional-statements, immutability

I have an input `[String]` as follows:

```
main = do
  let res = calcCounts ["IOIOOIOOI\r","OOIIIOOO\r",...]
```

I would like to count `I` and `O` instances **in order** using a non-uniform base system.

I created a `Type`:

```
data OutputState = OutputState { totNumI :: Int,
                                 totNumO :: Int,
                                 numI :: Int,
                                 numO :: Int
                               } deriving (Show)
```

The code I have created so far attempts to step through the input and create a new `OutputState` each time whilst taking into account the previous `OutputState` before hitting the completed conditions which is `'\r'` for each `[Char]` and the end of list for the `[String]` but is not complete:

```
calcCounts :: [String] -> [OutputState]
calcCounts input = map genOutputState input

genOutputState :: [Char] -> OutputState
genOutputState (x:xs)
  | x == '\r' = --return final OutputState 
  | otherwise do                 
      let currOutputState = incrementOutputState x
      genOutputState xs --also pass current OutputState back each recursion

incrementOutputState :: OutputState -> Char -> OutputState
incrementOutputState pos@prevOS x = do
  | if x == 'I' = do 
      let currOutputState = OutputState pos{totNumA} pos{totNumB} pos{numA}+1 pos{numB}
      | if currOutputState{numA} == 4 = OutputState currOutputState{totNumA}+1 currOutputState{totNumB} 0 0         
  | otherwise = do 
      let currentOutputState = OutputState pos{totNumA} pos{totNumB} pos{numA} pos{numB}+1
      | if currentOutputState{numB} == 4 = OutputState currOutputState{totNumA} currOutputState{totNumB}+1 0 0
```

The final output should be `[OutputState,OutputState,..]`

I know that my code is currently not legal and there is missing logic. Apologies for that. I am still in the process of returning to both Haskell and functional programming in general. In a imperative paradigm I would make use of mutable variables in order to track the necessary counts but understand this is not the correct way to think about the problem in a functional sense.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: I do not quite understand what exactly you are trying to do. Could you elaborate on the differences between `totNumA` and `numA`? And what is the result of `genOutputState "IOIOOIOOI\r"` supposed to be?

Comment: `pos{totNumA} pos{totNumB} pos{numA}+1 pos{numB}` are invalid. You simply pattern match on `pos@OutputState {totNumA=a, totNumB=b}` and then in the expression write `pos {totNumA = a+1}`  for example.

Comment: Sorry for that @RikVanToor, The desired output would be `[OutputState,OutputState,..]` whereby for that example the contents would be the `{ totNumI=1, totNumO=1, numI=0, num0=0 }`. I have changed `OutputState` from As and Bs to Is and Os to make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for this @WillemVanOnsem, I do understand what you mean but my syntax is weak. I'm having a lot of trouble working with `OutputState`. For example, it is not currently passed from `genOutputState` to `incrementOutputState` because of the recursion would cause `let currOutputState = incrementOutputState (OutputState 0 0 0 0) x` to reset `OutputState` for each `Char` in the `[Char]`.

Comment: not clear what you want to do. I think just counting equal elements in a list. Just, folding the list using `Data.Map` as an accumulator and `insertwith (+)` as the function should work. I don't get the non-uniform bases

Comment: @Ismor, if the `numI` or `numO` count hits 4 I need to increment `totNumI` or `totNumO` respectively and then reset `numI` and `numO` back to zero. Would that be possible using this type of fold? I have another set of counts above this that need to work in a similar way but I didn't include them for simplicity.

Comment: Why would that even be necessary though? You could just count the total number of I's, and then divide it by 4 and round down to get the `totNumI`

Comment: If `numI` reaches 4 then both `numI` and `numO` get set back to zero. If for example there were 3 instances or `O` prior to `numI` reaching 4 then those `O`s should not be included in the count. Like a multiple round, 'first to 4' system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're trying to do, although I am still not entirely sure if I understand it correctly.

```hs
data OutputState = OutputState { totNumI :: Int,
                                 totNumO :: Int,
                                 numI :: Int,
                                 numO :: Int
                               } deriving (Show)

genOutputState :: String -> OutputState
genOutputState = foldl incrementOutputState (OutputState 0 0 0 0)

incrementOutputState :: OutputState -> Char -> OutputState
incrementOutputState (OutputState ti to 3 no)  'I' = OutputState (ti + 1) to 0 0
incrementOutputState (OutputState ti to ni no) 'I' = OutputState ti to (ni + 1) no
incrementOutputState (OutputState ti to ni 3)  'O' = OutputState ti (to + 1) 0 0
incrementOutputState (OutputState ti to ni no) 'O' = OutputState ti to ni (no + 1)
incrementOutputState os _                          = os -- Do not increment anything for characters other than 'I' and 'O'
```

I would recommend you to follow some more Haskell tutorials, as I feel like you do not quite understand the syntax and the functional way of thinking yet.

Comment: I have a follow up question I hope you don't mind answering. What is the functionality used to 'pass through' the `String` supplied to `genOutputState`? Is it as simple as the fact it is not referenced in the function declaration (i.e. `genOutputState str = ..`)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @macourtney7 That is called eta reduction. Eta reduction means that `(\x -> f  x)` is the same thing as just `f`. In this case, this means that `getOutputState str = foldl incrementOutputState (OutputState 0 0 0 0) str` can also be written as `getOutputState = foldl incrementOutputState (OutputState 0 0 0 0)`